# Is there a way to find a Fisher score for each individual row?

Tags: python

I know that Fisher score is used for feature selection but I want to compute the Fisher score in each dataset row. The dataset contains 916 samples with 4 features and a target.

Dataset sample:

```
       C1           C2         C3          C4      flag
0   0.010760    0.289112    0.000000    0.000000    1
1   0.054865    0.060470    0.520228    0.000000    1
2   0.010760    0.289112    0.000000    0.000000    0
3   0.054865    0.060470    0.520228    0.000000    1
4   0.035029    0.030795    0.520228    0.575762    1
5   0.053166    0.057077    0.520228    0.000000    1
6   0.053166    0.060470    0.520228    0.000000    0
7   0.053166    0.073231    0.520228    0.000000    0
8   0.054865    0.289112    0.520228    0.000000    1
```

I tried to apply the fisher score function found [here](http://featureselection.asu.edu/tutorial.php) using the following code, but it does not give the expected results.

```
from skfeature.function.similarity_based import fisher_score
def score(x):
    return fisher_score.fisher_score(np.array(df.iloc[x, 0:4]), np.array(df.iloc[x, -1]))
```

results I get with the above code:

```
    C1     C2       C3       C4     flags
0   0      0        0        0        0
1   2.2    2.2      2.2      2.2      0
2   0      0        0        0        2.2
3   0      0        0        0        0
```

The expected output is to use the columns `C1-C4` and find an overall score for each row. Is there a way to do modify it in order to give me the results I want?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The Fisher score is used to calculate the *amount of information* of a variable (in your case the rows). I don't think it makes sense to apply it to a single column. What do you want to measure?

Comment: I think I want a value between 0 and 1 that represents the four columns (C1-C4) and maybe indicate the flag label.

Comment: What do you mean by "represents the four columns". The Fisher score gives a value for every feature but your rows are not features but samples

Comment: What can I use in order to have an overall score for each row?

Comment: Depends on what you want to measure. I don't understand what your expected outcome is or what you want to measure